# Kafka Consumer Continuously sending TCP packets to Kafka Server

Tags: tcp, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a Kafka consumer which is consuming the messages perfectly.
But the thing is , When the Kafka consumer started, the consumer is sending lot of TCP packets to Kafka Broker. I can sniff those packets using Wireshark.

Our Team understanding is like, It should send the TCP packet whenever the message is getting produced by the  Producer and the Consumer should be able to consume those messages by sending a request to Broker. (Like Event Driven)

We cannot really understand why the TCP packets are getting transferred between the Broker and Consumer continuously when the consumer is getting started.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka works as a **pull based** system communicating over TCP. That's why consumers continuously send TCP requests (poll() request and heartbeats, actually). You can check [this](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_pull) link for more information about this design decision of Kafka.